# led is not glowing but the code is getting executed

Tags: pi-3

[image]

and this is the code

```
import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led=12

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)

while true:
       GPIO.output(led,GPIO.HIGH)
       print "Led on"
       time.sleep(1)


       GPIO.output(led,GPIO.LOW)
       print "Led off"
       time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Try reversing the LED. The flat side is negative (the cathode) and the longer leg is positive. (the anode). Unlike resistors LED's have a polarity,
 they only work when connected the right way, like a battery.

Comment: I tried. It still does not work

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have connected the LED to GPIO 12 which is connected to expansion header pin 32.

You are using pin numbering (GPIO.BOARD).

Either use GPIO numbering (GPIO.BCM) or move the LED to pin 12 or use led=32 in your code.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3

Comment: Tried the other way round. No output.

Comment: When you have corrected the code or the wiring (or both) could you edit your question to show the current code and the current wiring? If you haven't used this cobbler before the ribbon cable may be inserted the wrong way around at one end.

Comment: Your setup command should have a comma ! GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)

Comment: Its comma only. typing error in above code